# Use map to loop over multiple variables to regress in nested dataset

Tags: r, purrr

- I have a nested dataset, where each row contains in a column a tibble with a subset of the main dataset.
- I want to run regressions over each of these subsets, where I vary the dependent variable.
- I built a function to do this taking only one variable as the dependent variable.
- I'm trying to use map to loop over multiple possible dependent variables but it seems as if the formula is not being interpreted correctly.

```r
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(rlang)

reg_across_groups <- function(df, var) {

  df <- df %>% 
    nest(data = -c("cyl"))

  var_enq <- rlang::enquo(var)

  model_formula <- formula(paste0(rlang::quo_name(var_enq), "~  hp"))

  df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(model = purrr::map(data, ~lm(model_formula, data = .x)))
}

# Works
reg_across_groups(mtcars, mpg)
reg_across_groups(mtcars, "mpg")

# Does not work
c("mpg", "wt") %>% 
  map(~ reg_across_groups(mtcars, .))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object '.' not found
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to symbol with `ensym`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
 reg_across_groups <- function(df, var) {
  var <- ensym(var)
  df <- df %>% 
    nest(data = -c("cyl"))



  model_formula <- formula(paste0(var, "~  hp"))

  df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(model = purrr::map(data, ~lm(model_formula, data = .x)))
}





c("mpg", "wt") %>% 
   map(~ reg_across_groups(mtcars, !!.x))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl            data model 
#  <dbl> <list<df[,10]>> <list>
#1     6        [7 × 10] <lm>  
#2     4       [11 × 10] <lm>  
#3     8       [14 × 10] <lm>  

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl            data model 
#  <dbl> <list<df[,10]>> <list>
#1     6        [7 × 10] <lm>  
#2     4       [11 × 10] <lm>  
#3     8       [14 × 10] <lm>  



reg_across_groups(mtcars, mpg)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl            data model 
#  <dbl> <list<df[,10]>> <list>
#1     6        [7 × 10] <lm>  
#2     4       [11 × 10] <lm>  
#3     8       [14 × 10] <lm>  

reg_across_groups(mtcars, "mpg")
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl            data model 
#  <dbl> <list<df[,10]>> <list>
#1     6        [7 × 10] <lm>  
#2     4       [11 × 10] <lm>  
#3     8       [14 × 10] <lm>
```

Comment: So in this case, the map would work, but not just the variable name without quotes as in the style of tidyverse function. It's a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @jyiow DO you want to pass both?

Comment: It would be more flexible if both ways could be called if it's not too complex.